# IIS 7 Ignores web.config sessionState mode="SQLServer" and always uses in process. Help?

Tags: iis-7, web-config, session-state

I have went through almost everything to get my session state lasting longer then 30 minutes including moving it to a SQL server.  I know everything is 100% correct in my web.config as it worked perfect in development. The connection string also is used in my entity so I know my process can connect to it.

Besides that, another way I know it is simply ignoring it is if I put an invalid connection string in development I get an SQL error, where I can put XASDASD in production and it never even attempts to connect, simply uses in process.

Is there any configuration that IIS7 possess that may be disabling my ability to override the session state?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps given in [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753897%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: i did to setup my table.  I just enabled ASP.NET State service but SQL Server Agent won't start.  Still state does not appear to work, however I do not believe SQL Server Agent is used to create states, only purge them, correct?

Comment: Actually I just verified on a box I am already using this on.  Neither are running on that so that cannot be the issue.  Something has to be setup on this server telling it not to allow me to override that setting....